# Prevent CSS animation on parent element from applying to a child element

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

Let's say I have a `div` element that represents one slide in a carousel. This `div` has a title, content, and footer as structured below.

```
<div class='slide one'>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
  <div>Footer</div>
</div>
```

If I wanted to apply CSS animations to the entire `.slide` class -- for example, having it move in from the left -- is there a way to prevent the title from inheriting that animation class and simply staying static?

To be clear, I want all of the content to swap out by using jQuery to apply animate.css classes. The title on `slide two` will simply be identical to the title on `slide one`.  I just want to know if it's possible to have animations applied to the `slide` class exclude certain child elements so they appear static while the content below them swaps.

Yes, I am aware that restructuring the code and placing the title outside the slide would achieve this same effect, but it's not feasible in this situation.

Comment: The CSS for the slider elements themselves is inconsequential -- it can be literally anything.  You can add or remove classes at your leisure or style them however you choose, since the slider is implemented via jQuery. The CSS for the animations is using animate.css: 'fadeInLeft animated' classes.

Comment: No, that is not possible – same as when you put a coin into a shoe box, and then move the shoe box around … you can hardly expect the coin stay where is was (in relation to the outside). So you can either place the coin outside of the shoe box, or you will have to animate the coin to perform the “reverse” of your shoe box movement.

Comment: I assumed as much, but I thought perhaps someone knew of a z-index trick or a way to use !important that might overrule the animation effects. Wishful thinking, I guess.

Comment: Well for some animation, like slide from left, you could setup the "title" to animate from its "going to end up" position related to the slide's start and then animate it to its original position. This way it appears to be not moving.

Comment: @LGSon Could you elaborate a little more? This seems promising, and I think I'm following, but I'd need to write my own animation class for it, correct?

Comment: If "slide" start at -100px and will stop at 0px, then "title" could start at 100px and end up at 0px. This means they slide towards each other but as "title" is inside "slide" it will stand still, kind of _one step to left and then one step to right_, ... so 1 anim. for the slide and 1 for the title.

Comment: Another way, maybe even better with less complicated calculations, is of course to not animate the slide itself, but its children, and in this case all but the "title", where they start from a negative position. Using this method you can use pretty much any animation effect, same on all or one for each.

Comment: @LGSon I've got it working to cancel the sliding-from-left effect by reversing the animation with a new class, but animate.css also applies an opacity change (0 to 1) that I can't seem to circumvent since it applies to the parent element.

Comment: Opacity set on parent will effect children too, so keeping your html structure you can't stop it from animate opacity on all the children, so to fix that you have to animate the slide's children instead, which actually is a much more clever way to do it, where you kind of have no limits at all with what you can do, ... which is exactly what the jQuery answer is actually doing using script, but you could do it with css only.

Comment: Well there is one exception, if you use alpha background color instead of opacity, then you can animate the slide's background and not the children

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot restructure the slider to operate only on certain children. The slider is reused in numerous other areas of the site and only in this one section does it require this hack of not animating the title.

Comment: Then you have an answer using script which will do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell the `jquery` selector not to include a subelement while applying the `animate` function but just using `:not` operator. The following would just change the opacity of `p` and `div` but not `h1`.

```
<div class='slide one'>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
  <div>Footer</div>
</div>

  <script>
$().ready(function(){
      $('.slide').find(":not('h1')").animate({
         opacity : 0.1
        },1000); });
</script>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mnq7yqch/

**EDIT :**

You may also make use of `.complete` function which gives you the leverage to change properties of the selected elements.

```
 $('.slide').find(":not('h1')").animate({
   marginLeft: '+=138px'
}, {
duration: 3000,
complete: function() {
  $(this).addClass("slide1");
}
  });
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/mnq7yqch/2/

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, and if no one else chimes in with a better solution I'll credit you, but I don't think it's workable in my situation. I'm applying animate.css classes via jQuery's .addClass() to achieve animations.

Comment: I've updated the solution with another solution that would help you with classes.